# Viewcell binding context is not working in xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, relativesource

I have a listview and many viewcells. The Itemstemplate are selected by using MessageTemplateSelector class. In MainViewModel there is a Messages collection. I have bind the Message collection into the listview. It's working fine. But the viewcell UI element is binded with viewmodel property named as ShowSenderIcon, that is not binded into the UI element. I have tried many suggestion. But it is not working. My sample code is mentioned below, Please refer, My requirement is i want to hide the Frame by using viewmodel (ShowSenderIcon) property.

I have tried this,

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<sync:SfListView
  x:Name="ListView"
  Grid.Row="0"
  Margin="0"
  AutoFitMode="Height"
  IsBusy="True"
  ItemSize="100"
  ItemSpacing="10"
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageTemplateSelector}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
  SelectionMode="None"
  VerticalOptions="Start"/>
```

**IncomingViewCell.cs**

```
<Frame
  x:Name="avatorFrame"
  CornerRadius="25"
  HasShadow="false"
  IsVisible="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ShowSenderIcon, Source={x:Reference ListView}, Mode=TwoWay}"
  OutlineColor="Gray"/>
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
private bool showSenderIcon = false;
public bool ShowSenderIcon
{
   get { return showSenderIcon; }
   set { showSenderIcon = value; OnPropertyChanged("ShowSenderIcon"); }
}

private ObservableCollection<Message> messagesList;
public ObservableCollection<Message> Messages
{
   get { return messagesList; }
   set { messagesList = value; }
}

public MainPageViewModel()
{
   Messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>();
   Messages.Add(new Message { Text = "Hi", IsIncoming = true, MessagDateTime = DateTime.Now, ShowTimeStamp = false });
}
```

Comment: Are you get any exception?

Comment: I don't see why you need the `MarkupExtension`, you can simply do this: `IsVisible="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ShowSenderIcon, Source={x:Reference Source ListView}}` also you might want to choose a different name than "ListView". Lastly, I don't see the need for the `TwoWay` mode, so lose that for now to rule it out

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, Thanks for your reply, I have already tried as mentioned in your suggestion,  it throws **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException**

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, any suggestion for this exception?

Comment: Can you share any details on when and where that exception occurs?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, When IncomingViewcell template is appear then the exception is occurs.

Comment: I don't think that code is in the question?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, please refer my updated question.

Comment: @Gokul, are you checked intialization?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed listview intialization on android and ios.